# Big data upload to server, better in chunks?

Tags: excel, vba

I've inherited a set of excel VBA macros that grabs the data from a spreadsheet and uploads the data to a database (SQL DB).  The problem is the insane amount of time it takes when the data is "big" (46 columns * 10,500 rows on a particular sheet).  It seems to me that it would be better to chunk the data to get it to the database, but is this correct?  If so, what would be the best way to go about it?  I'm currently trying encapsulating the following code in a for loop that chunks it into 500 rows, but it's not elegant as vba is not my forte.

```
    Sub Upload_Claims()

    Dim SubmissionNumber As Integer
    Dim LoopVar As Integer, row As Integer

    Set cnnConn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnnConn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=" & Server & ";database=happyfunserver"
    cnnConn.Open

    SubmissionNumber = Sheets("Quality Check").Range("SubID").Value

    'Upload HPL - PPL
    Set cmdCommand = New ADODB.Command
    Set cmdCommand.ActiveConnection = cnnConn
    With cmdCommand
        .CommandText = "Select * from losses where submission_id = " & SubmissionNumber
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .Execute
    End With

    ' Open the recordset.
    Set rstRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rstRecordset.ActiveConnection = cnnConn
    rstRecordset.Open cmdCommand, , adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

    'upload '

    Sheets("PL").Select
    row = 8

    Do While Range("C" & row).Value <> vbNullString

      With rstRecordset
        .AddNew
        .Fields("submission_id") = SubmissionNumber

        If Range("A" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
            .Fields("tag_id") = Range("A" & row).Value
        End If
        If Range("B" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
            .Fields("batch_tag_id") = Range("B" & row).Value
        End If
        If Range("C" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
            .Fields("source") = Left(Range("C" & row).Value, 250)
        End If
        If IsDate(Range("D" & row).Value) Then
            .Fields("evaluation_date") = Range("D" & row).Value
        End If



        If Range("E" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
          If Range("E" & row).Value = "HPL" Then
          .Fields("coverage_type_id") = 22
          ElseIf Range("E" & row).Value = "PL" Then
          .Fields("coverage_type_id").Value = 2
          End If
        End If
        '--------------'

        If Range("F" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
            .Fields("claim_no") = Left(Range("F" & row).Value, 250)
        End If
        If Range("G" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
            .Fields("claimant") = Left(Range("G" & row).Value, 200)
        End If


        'upload layer'

        If Range("H" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
          If UCase(Range("H" & row).Value) = "UNKNOWN" Then
          .Fields("layer_id") = 0
          ElseIf UCase(Range("H" & row).Value) = "AAA" Then
          .Fields("layer_id") = 1
          ElseIf UCase(Range("H" & row).Value) = "BBBBBB" Then
          .Fields("layer_id") = 2
          ElseIf UCase(Range("H" & row).Value) = "CCCCC" Then
          .Fields("layer_id") = 3
          ElseIf UCase(Range("H" & row).Value) = "DDDDDDDD" Then
          .Fields("layer_id") = 4
          ElseIf UCase(Range("H" & row).Value) = "EEE" Then
          .Fields("layer_id") = 5
          End If
        End If
        '-------------------'

        If Range("I" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
            .Fields("aaaaaaaa_name") = Left(Range("I" & row).Value, 100)
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Range("J" & row).Value) And Range("J" & row).Value <> 0 Then
            .Fields("bbb_id") = Left(Range("J" & row).Value, 7)
        End If
        If Not IsError(Range("K" & row).Value) Then
            .Fields("ccc_id_verified") = Range("K" & row).Value
        End If
        If Not IsError(Range("L" & row).Value) Then
            If Range("L" & row).Value <> vbNullString And Range("L" & row).Value <> 0 Then
                .Fields("dddddddd_city") = Left(Range("L" & row).Value, 80)
            End If
        End If
        If Range("M" & row).Value <> vbNullString And Range("M" & row).Value <> 0 Then
            .Fields("eeeeeeee_fips") = Left(Range("M" & row).Value, 5)
        End If
        If Not IsError(Range("N" & row).Value) Then
            If Range("N" & row).Value <> vbNullString And Range("N" & row).Value <> 0 Then
            .Fields("ffffffff_stateabbr") = Left(Range("N" & row).Value, 2)
            End If
        End If
        If IsDate(Range("O" & row).Value) Then
            .Fields("gggggggg_date") = Range("O" & row).Value
        End If
        If IsDate(Range("P" & row).Value) Then
            .Fields("hhhhhh_date") = Range("P" & row).Value
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Range("Q" & row).Value) Or Range("Q" & row).Value = 0 Then
            .Fields("iiiiiiiii_paid") = Range("Q" & row).Value
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Range("R" & row).Value) Or Range("R" & row).Value = 0 Then
            .Fields("jjjjjjjjj_reserve") = Range("R" & row).Value
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Range("S" & row).Value) Or Range("S" & row).Value = 0 Then
            .Fields("kkkk_paid") = Range("S" & row).Value
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Range("T" & row).Value) Or Range("T" & row).Value = 0 Then
            .Fields("llll_reserve") = Range("T" & row).Value
        End If


        'upload claim status'

        If Range("U" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
           If UCase(Range("U" & row).Value) = "CLOSED" Then
           .Fields("status_id") = 1
           ElseIf UCase(Range("U" & row).Value) = "OPEN" Then
           .Fields("status_id") = 0
           ElseIf UCase(Range("U" & row).Value) = "REOPEN" Then
           .Fields("status_id") = 2
           End If
        End If
        '---------------------------'

        If IsDate(Range("V" & row).Value) Then
            .Fields("closed_date") = Range("V" & row).Value
        End If
        If Range("W" & row).Value <> vbNullString Then
            .Fields("description") = Range("W" & row).Value
        End If


            If IsNumeric(Range("AN" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("manual") = Range("AN" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AB" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("11111") = Range("AB" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AC" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("2222222") = Range("AC" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AD" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("33333333333") = Range("AD" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AE" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("444444444") = Range("AE" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AF" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("55555555") = Range("AF" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AG" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("666666666") = Range("AG" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AH" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("7777777777777") = Range("AH" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AI" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("other") = Range("AI" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AJ" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("88") = Range("AJ" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AK" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("cause") = Range("AK" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AL" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("dept") = Range("AL" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AM" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("outcome") = Range("AM" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AS" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("report_lag") = Range("AS" & row).Value
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Range("AT" & row).Value) Then
                .Fields("closed_lag") = Range("AT" & row).Value
            End If


        .Update
    End With
    row = row + 1
    If row Mod 25 = 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "PL" & " - " & row
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop
Application.StatusBar = "Performing " & "PL" & " Batch Update..."

rstRecordset.UpdateBatch

'(Similar loop repeats for 5 different pieces)


End Sub
```

Any advice is appreciated.  I tried to keep it short, but it's hard when you don't know what you are really doing or what direction to go.

Comment: I reckon processing record by record will always be slow-you'd be better using a single query with a closed workbook as the data source: `cnnConn.Execute "INSERT INTO losses (C1,C2,C3) SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Development\MyImport.xlsm].[Sheet1$]"` if you can

Comment: One option may be to write the sql insert or update statements to a .sql file that can be executed against the database directly with one commit at the end for the whole transaction. Inserting or updating approx 10k rows should not take very long.

Comment: Those are some interesting field names. "gggggggg_date"? "7777777777777"? Just curious.  Did you anonymize the code before posting it or are those actually the field names?

Comment: Yes, field names were changed to protect the innocent, @PowerUser. :)

Comment: @JosieP, I think you are on to something, but the big hang comes at the rstRecordset.UpdateBatch command, which is why I'm thinking chunks in the first place.  Will it push up faster or the same with the single query?

Comment: @ChrisProsser, is that written in as sql or within vba?

Comment: @TheJ, I'm just brainstorming here.  Would this be faster if you saved the data as a delimited text file and then bulk inserted that into your SQL DB?

Comment: @The Jhe I would consider using VBA to parse the values into SQL and write the sql to a file.

Comment: @PowerUser could you show me how to do that in VBA? I don't know how to even begin doing that *flails spastically*

Comment: Actually, nevermind.  JosieP's suggestion is probably the best way to go. Skip the updatebatch completely and use the Insert instead.

Comment: How many records do you get in SQL when you run `Select * from losses where submission_id = AnyRecentNumber`? I ask because your UpdateBatch statement looks like it is both updating those records with the *exact same values* AND adding the new records. If you take out the `rstRecordset.Open` line, does it run faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversations and how I *think* your code works, here's one untested solution you can try that may speed it up by moving the bulk of processing to SQL.  Unfortunately, you'll have to skip the in-recordset-processing method you already have.  According to google, you can't use an ADO.Recordset as the source for a SQL query (they're in different parts of memory and don't see each other).  So, you can try this:

1. Create a staging table on your SQL Server. Let's call it TblStaging because why not.  The data types for this staging table will be nothing but large string fields so it can hold anything you put into it including errors.
2. Right after you declare the connection string, try JosieP's suggested Insert statement to load your data to TblStaging. Comment out all the VBA after that.
3. Make a .sql file that will validate your data according to the rules in your VBA and then move it to your permanent SQL table. (I'm assuming you know enough SQL to be able to do this.) Since this is all now in SQL and not VBA, it should be much faster.
4. This sql file will have to be run somehow.  If you don't want to do it manually every time, there's 2 options (assuming you are good enough with SQL Server):
   4a. Figure out how to run your .sql from a command line and run a batch file invoking that command line from VBA.
   4b. Set it up as a regularly recurring agent.

Comment: I think you and @JosieP are right, so I'm going to attempt this solution.  Hopefully, I can put it together quickly and will comment back with the results.

Comment: Looking forward to it. Also, how slow is the current process? Is it worth the time refactoring the code and potentially creating new bugs?

Comment: So after presenting today, the group I work with decided to shelve the project (*slaps head*).  I'm still going to try it out on my own and see if I can make the donuts faster.  Thanks.